# how to Post status to facebook and twitter from asp.net mvc website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I know that I can use the Facebook and twitter sdk to post on both, but I am asking if there is a simple tool or examples shows how to do that.

What I want to do that users will connect to facebook and twitter in my website and then there will be a textbox to let them send status messages to both, something like what twitter is doing http://puu.sh/6VXr

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to do something custom, I would try to use the existing JavaScript widgets, since they should require less maintenance than using the SDK.

- For Twitter, there are a few simple Javascript widgets you can include: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-for-websites
- Facebook has something similar, but I'm not sure whether the user can enter a message (it's a Like button): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

If these don't do what you want, there are also some third-party kits that will make this easier, so you don't have to use each individual SDK, such as ShareKit: http://www.getsharekit.com/